# How to manage the white balance in webcam

Tags: camera, color-management

On Linux my webcam works fine, but when using artificial lighting the white-balance is too reddish. Color look fine with natural illumination.
Is there a way to calibrate the colors or have some form of auto-adjustment which works?

I used `guvcview` to tinker with the settings but haven't managed to find a suitable combination of settings to show natural colors.

Comment: Did you try VLC? It has a lot video related tools.

Answer (score 33):

At least on my webcam, the `v4l2-ctl -l` command shows two settings related to white balance:

```
# v4l2-ctl -l
[...]
 white_balance_temperature_auto (bool)   : default=1 value=1
[...]
      white_balance_temperature (int)    : min=2800 max=6500 step=1 default=4000 value=4000 flags=inactive
[...]
```

I must set the `white_balance_temperature_auto` setting to 0 before the `white_balance_temperature` setting will have any effect.

```
# v4l2-ctl -c white_balance_temperature_auto=0
# v4l2-ctl -c white_balance_temperature=3000  # or whatever value you want
```

Note that the `white_balance_temperature` setting controls what the camera assumes the lighting environment to be, so decreasing the value makes the camera assume the ambient light is more reddish, and so it will make the picture more bluish to compensate.

Use the `-d` option to use a specific video device like `-d /dev/video0`.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a functional GUI for v4l2-ctl: [camset](https://github.com/azeam/camset). In addition to white balance one might also have to adjust things like hue and saturation.